# mat-checkbox targeting both elements on same click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I have one `mat-checkbox` which is also part of mobile version.

When we have two separate parts, one for desktop and one for mobile.
The desktop `<mat-checkbox>` works on select and unselect properly, whereas the mobile option when we click triggers the desktop version checkbox instead of just selecting and unselecting the mobile version.

How to let `<mat-checkbox>` handle both events separately independent of each other?

HTML:

```
<div class="class-a">
  <label
    [ngClass]="{'class-b': valueTrigger}">
    <mat-checkbox
      class="checkbox"
      [(ngModel)]="valueTrigger"
      (input)="toggleHasTrigger($event.target.checked)"
      id="test"
      type="checkbox"
      name="testing" ngDefaultControl
    >
      I am here!
    </mat-checkbox>
  </label>
</div>
```

TS:

```
initValueTrigger(): void {
    this.valueTrigger = !this.asset.Unchecked;
    this.toggleHasTriggerEvent.emit(this.valueTrigger);
  }
    
toggleHasTrigger(toggleValue: boolean): void {
        this.asset.Unchecked = !toggleValue;
        this.valueTrigger = toggleValue;
        this.toggleHasTriggerEvent.emit(this.valueTrigger);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to provide separate ids to the checkboxes for both mobile and web views

For example: `test_web and test_mobile`

Answer (score 0):

I used the `for` instead of `id` after the above answer to have separate ids to the checkboxes:

```
for="test"
```